# Python equation substitution

Tags: python, equation

So i am starting with python and was wondering how i could substitute numbers for variables into that equation into a equation (python 2.7.2) help please?

for example

```
def main():
   e = raw_input("input equation here")
   g = input("number to substitute")
```

so you "e" would be a equation in terms of g and you could replace the g value that has a numerical value in the original equation. Sorry its kind of confusing, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [sympy](http://sympy.org/):

```
import sympy

def main():
   e = sympy.sympify(raw_input("input equation here: "))
   g = input("number to substitute for g: ")
   print 'e=',e.subs({'g':g})
```

Comment: so im getting a parse error, sorry im a newbie what does can not parse mean, thank you

Comment: I'd guess it means it can't parse the equation you're giving as input. What is it you're typing ?

Comment: something like 3g or something just to test it out

Comment: **** found out what the problem was, you have to do 3 * g instead of 3g thanks for the help :D